# With Helm 3 and K8s cluster w/RBAC (X509 certs), what permissions does Helm need? I think it creates ConfigMaps for release info?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-rbac

I have setup my cluster (k3d) to have some RBAC rules and also created a certificate to identify my user for `kubectl` commands. I've set the user to have a `Role` via a `RoleBinding` in a specific namespace.

I want to make it so they could create `Deployment`s, `Pod`s, `Service`s but not create a `Secret` or `ConfigMap`. If I do that though, will they be able to use Helm to install things? Doesn't Helm store its info about releases in `Secret`s or `ConfigMap`s?

Do I need to grant the user access to also create those things?

*Example Role*

```yaml
#################################################################################
################################## Example Role #################################
#################################################################################

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-role
  namespace: my-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]

    # Leaving out "configmaps" and "secrets"
    resources: ["pods","deployments","services"]
    verbs: ["*"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes unfortunately you have to. But from the bright side you can put limitations by defining verbs as

```
["get, list, create"]
```

not

```
["*"]
```

This gives full authority.
I suggest you to check https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac
to get a clear view and determine your needs and abilities on the kubernetes side.

Example verbs:

```
verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

Also you can check your users abilities by using the can-i tool in the link below.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/

Hope these links can help you.

Btw, look at the charts and yaml files for Kind: labels.

Those are the things you will need access to.

Comment: Right but the limitations won't really do anything, correct? Because Helm will need the critical CRUD ones: `["get", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]`. And that'll give the user the ability to change all the secrets/configmaps in the namespace.

Comment: "Btw, look at the charts and yaml files for Kind: labels" Where are these? Do you just mean do a  google search for some examples? Or is there a specific repo that has these?

Comment: I meant google for examples if you need. If the links are insufficient. :)